# Hover over nav bar change transparent logo to filled logo

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my logo to change from a transparent background to a filled background when the user hovers over the navigation.

Currently, my JQuery works on hover but when the user moves off the navigation the logo doesn't change back to the transparent logo.

```
<div class="logo">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> 
    <img src="/Includes/images/holts-logo-trans.png" class="img-fluid" />
  </a>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.navbar-light').hover(function () {
    $('.logo a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/holts-logo-fill.png');
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes two parameters. A function to run when hovered and a function to run when no longer hovered. Use the second parameter to set the `src` attribute back to the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) accepts two functions; first is called when mouse enters, and second is called when mouse leaves the element.

So you need to set the transparent logo image in the second function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navbar-light').hover(function () {
        $('.logo a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/holts-logo-fill.png');
    }, function() {
        $('.logo a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/holts-logo-trans.png');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try mouseover and mouseout events

```
<div class="logo">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/Includes/images/holts-logo-trans.png" class="img-fluid" /></a>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navbar-light').on('mouseover',function () {
        $('.logo a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/holts-logo-fill.png');
    }).on('mouseout', function(){
       $('.logo a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/holts-logo-trans.png');
    });
});
```

Comment: Be careful. The companion event for `mouseover` is `mouseout`. Equivalently, `mouseenter` pairs with `mouseleave`. They differ on how they deal with bubbled events.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, thanks for pointing out. I have updated in post